# Sonarqube 6.7.5 Calculating Code Coverage even when the project does not have src/main/java folder

Tags: javascript, java, maven, sonarqube

When I run an analysis on a UI project with only JS code in it, and no src/main/java folder, the quality gate for code coverage fails. Before on 5.6.6, it was working fine. After upgrade to 6.7.5, I started seeing this issue.

I use Jenkins Sonar for running analysis using maven.

```
[ERROR] Coverage: 0.0 < 60
[ERROR] Critical Issues: 277 > 0
[ERROR] Blocker Issues: 38 > 0
[ERROR] [BUILD BREAKER] Project did not meet 3 conditions
```

Comment: Doesn't it tell you *why* it failed?

Comment: @Andreas I have a quality gate which is set for minimum 60% code coverage. This should only be run if java code is available. In this case, even without any java code, the quality gate fails.

Comment: could this be due to this bug reported https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9384? Fix release version marked on it is 7.2

Comment: @Raj this is a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked around this issue using the

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.js
```

Now the analysis scope has been reduced to avoid .js files from coverage report.